# Convert strings of tags to binary vector pyspark

Tags: pyspark, one-hot-encoding

I have data which looks like this:

```
| Id | ----Tags---- | some_text |
| 0  | <a><b>       | ex1       |
| 1  | <a><c>       | ex2       |
| 2  | <b><c>       | ex3       |
```

and I want it to end up looking like this:

```
| Id | a | b | c | some_text |
| 0  | 1 | 1 | 0 | ex1       |
| 1  | 1 | 0 | 1 | ex2       |
| 2  | 0 | 1 | 1 | ex3       |
```

and I would like to use pyspark for the solution. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't already know the expected categorical values, you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.udf` to split and tags into an array of values and `pyspark.sql.functions.explode` function to convert them to columns. Then, you can pivot values to columns:

```
# required imports
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
import re

# regex pattern to split 'tagged values'
pat = re.compile('<(.*?)>')

#udf to split string to array of values
split_f = f.udf(lambda s: pat.split(s), ArrayType(StringType()))

# sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0,'<a><b>','ex1'),(1,'<a><c>','ex2')], ['Id', '---Tags---', 'some_text'])

+---+----------+---------+
| Id|---Tags---|some_text|
+---+----------+---------+
|  0|    <a><b>|      ex1|
|  1|    <a><c>|      ex2|
+---+----------+---------+

df.withColumn('exploded', 
   F.explode(split_f(F.col('---Tags---'))))
  .groupby('Id').pivot('exploded').count().na.fill(0).show()

+---+---+---+---+
| Id|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```